# Insert and not overwrite new uploads in updating record

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

When I update a record, i.e a Contact, the attachments (images) are overwritten. How do I just insert the the newly attached images and not get the old ones be overwritten? Please see my codes below (I am using Yii 2.0 PHP framework).

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{   
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $cur_businessname = $model->business_name;
    $attachment = $model->attachment;
    $files = array();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment');

        if($model->attachment) {
            if (empty($model->attachment)) {
                $model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'attachment');
                $path = 'assets/images/default.png';
                $model->attachment = $path;
            } else {                
                foreach ($model->attachment as $attachment) {
                    $path = 'archive/contact/'.$attachment->baseName.'.'.$attachment->extension;
                    $count = 0;
                    {
                        while(file_exists($path)) {
                           $path = 'archive/contact/'.$attachment->baseName.'_'.$count.'.'.$attachment->extension;
                           $count++;
                        }
                    }                        
                    $attachment->saveAs($path);
                    $files[] = $path; 
                }
                $model->attachment = implode(',', $files); 
            }
        } else {
            $model->attachment = $attachment;
        } 
        //$updatedAttachments = array_push($attachment,$path); 
        //var_dump($attachment);
        //exit;

        $model->save();

        if($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Success!");
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Contact Creation Failed!");
        }

        $model->refresh();
        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $session['user_id']]);
    } else {            
        return $this->renderAjax('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
    if (!empty($model->attachment)) {
        $model->attachment = explode(',', $model->attachment);
        $file = '';
        foreach ($model->attachment as $attachment) {
            $file.= Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/'. $attachment, ['class'=>'file-preview-image', 'alt'=>'Attachment', 'title'=>'Attachment']).',';
        }
        echo FileInput::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'attachment[]',
            'options' => ['multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'initialPreview'=>[ 
                    [$file,]
                ],
                'showCaption' => false,
                'showRemove' => false,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                'browseLabel' =>  'Attach Business Card',
                'maxFileCount' => 2,
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'], 
                'overwriteInitial' => true,
                'uploadAsync' => true,
                ],
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true]
        ]);
    } else {
        echo FileInput::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'imageUrl[]',
            'options' => ['multiple' => true],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'showCaption' => false,
                'showRemove' => false,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'maxFileCount' => 2,
                'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                'browseLabel' =>  'Attach Business Card',
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'], 
                ],
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true]
        ]);
    }
?>
```

I have tried `array_push` but it's not working. The `$attachment` on the 6th line of `actionUpdate` holds the old attachments. Now, I can't anymore use `$attachment` inside `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))` since it's already after posting/submitting the form.

How do I just insert the newly attached files without overwriting the old ones? Your comments/answers will be of great help!

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Comment: You do like doing things twice dont you `if($model->attachment) {` followed by `if (empty($model->attachment)) {` then `$model->save();` followed by `if($model->save()) {`

Comment: @InsaneSkulll done editing it. I am using Kartik widget.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: My comment pretty much says it all if you read it and then look at your code

Comment: @RiggsFolly would that help my current problem? My Update worked before this problem, tho.

Comment: No, but removing the `$model->save();` before the `if($model->save())` would stop you writing the model back to the database twice for no apparent reason.

Comment: oh I see thanks. but my problem is still not solved :(

Comment: try copy pasting code from create action.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll why? it would just like be creating, hence overwriting.